# Float not work correctly on CSS with certain item

Tags: html, css

when i use float left for my items ( about 100 item) it's not work for one of them and this item alone on a row . each item css code is :

```
div.products.span4 {
    float: right;
    padding: 2em;
}
```

can see  the example of the problem in below site .
[negareh taban](http://www.ntk.co.ir/?cat=3&lang=en) on item named `C110479` you see it's alone on a row .

how can fix this problem ?

Comment: have you tried using `clear:left`?

Comment: when use `clear left` all item go on one row !

Comment: @alek CTRL + F help you ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that item C110477 is 1 pixel taller than the neighbors, so the next row starts to the right of the right edge of the nearest floated object, which is C110477.

The extra pixel is due to the image height being 226px instead of 225px.

One way of fixing this is to specify the height of `div.products.span4` and set `overflow: hidden` that way all the floated elements have the same height regardless of any small variations in your image heights.

Answer (score 0):

```
.products:nth-of-type(3n+1) {
    clear:left;
}
```

works fine for me.